# q-field-no-input being added to fields

Tags: vue.js, quasar-framework

Does anyone know why the q-field-no-input class would be added to my fields even though there is an input inside it? This is happening in all of my pages and is creating a weird margin that breaks the formatting.

I would rather not override the CSS and just find out why the class is being added.

Comment: The [usage example](http://quasar-framework.org/components/field.html) for the `q-field` component in the docs show it being used with a `q-input` component. Can you double-check that you're using that and not a regular HTML `input` element? If you *are* using a `q-input` component, it's possible this is a bug in Quasar, and it might be a good idea to [create an issue](https://github.com/quasarframework/quasar/issues/new) on their issue tracker.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Had the same problem. Latest quasar used features of vue 2.5. Just upgrade to latest vuejs. My package.json now contains "vue": "~2.5.2" in dependencies, and "vue-template-compiler": "~2.5.2" in devDependencies. It solved my problem.

Answer (score 0):

Updating to latest version did not work for me. Had to resort to disabling the .q-field-no-input styles.

```
.q-field-with-error .q-field-no-input
  border-top 0
.q-field-no-input
  margin-top 0
```

This solves the issue (I am sure I have no fields without input so I do not worry about disabling it)